# VLOOKUP to compare data in 2 different workbooks with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find, vlookup

I am somewhat new to VBA/Excel, so I was wondering if someone would help me out.

My question:
I have two different workbooks but in these workbooks two of the columns have common data. Thus I wanted to use `VLOOKUP` to compare the two columns and see if there are common data.

Details:
1st workbook : has 3 different sheets, I only need to use the sheet "Items" which has the data in column 2.

2nd workbook: has only 1 sheet called "Data" and has data in column 4.

Thus my goal is to compare the 2 columns. In workbook1 there is an empty column next to the data column so, if there is a match I want to say "ok" in it. If no match then "".

I tried `VLOOKUP` but really could not understand it.  Plus this is for work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this..

Assuming the name of your second workbook is Book2.xlsx, then try this...

On First workbook
In C2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,'[Book2.xlsx]Data'!$D:$D,0)),"OK","")
```

and copy it down.

If you require a VBA solution, one approach to get the desired output is as below...
The following code assumes that both the Book1.xlsm (which will contain the below code) and Book2.xlsx are saved in the same folder.
If they are saved at different location, change the path and name of Book2.xlsx in the following lines of code.

```
sourceFilePath = dwb.Path & "\"
sourceFileName = "Book2.xlsx"
```

Code:

```
Sub CompareData()
Dim swb As Workbook, dwb As Workbook
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim slr As Long, dlr As Long, i As Long
Dim sourceFilePath As String, sourceFileName As String
Dim x, y, z, dict
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Items")
dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
x = dws.Range("B2:B" & dlr).Value
ReDim z(1 To dlr)
sourceFilePath = dwb.Path & "\"
sourceFileName = "Book2.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open sourceFilePath & sourceFileName

Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sws = swb.Sheets("Data")
slr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
y = sws.Range("D2:D" & slr).Value

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
    dict.Item(y(i, 1)) = ""
Next i
swb.Close False

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If dict.exists(x(i, 1)) Then
        z(i) = "OK"
    Else
        z(i) = ""
    End If
Next i
dws.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(x, 1), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(z)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I understand this, but i need to do it in vba code not excel thus why i am struggling.

Comment: Do you have a starting code or share whatever you have tried so far? If yes, what issues you are having with it?

Comment: I have added a code in my solution, see if that does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @sktnerr thank you, work perfectly.And again thanks alot now i understand

Comment: You're welcome Panscer! Glad it worked. Also don't forget to upvote the solution. :)

Comment: Ya sure, but it says lesser than 15 reputation won't work :'(, but yes thanks a lot really helped.