# using match funtion for 2 different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

i have been assigned to use the .match function in vba, to compare 2 different columns in 2 different workbooks.

here is my code so far.. how do i use the match function to my goal ?

```
    Sub Ob_match()
    Dim swb As Workbook, dwb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Range, oMatch As Range



Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sws = swb.Sheets("Item")

Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(swb.Path & "\EPC_EndItem.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Data")


    If Not oMatch Is Nothing Then
        oCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Y"
    Else
        oCell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
    End If
Next oCell
MsgBox "Processing completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: vlookup is the tool that you need.  A vba approach will be more complicated than this

Comment: yes but i need to do it with vba,thus the struggle

Comment: why do you have to do it with vba?  the most simple way to do this in vba would be harder, more work intensive, and probably use a lookup anyway

Comment: here's a tutorial if you're really set on this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx

Comment: Haha, thanks but its for work.. and i intend to use .Find not vlookup

Comment: just out of interest, what do you mean it's for work?  do your work not like vlookups?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VLOOKUP to compare data in 2 different workbooks with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221414/vlookup-to-compare-data-in-2-different-workbooks-with-vba) - that question is almost identical to this one, and includes a VBA solution which is said to have "work perfectly".

Comment: yes that is it , but now i jut want to use .find....

Comment: You can use `COUNTIF` or `MATCH` functions if you don't like `VLOOKUP`. If you know nothing about VBA, this is going to be very hard for you to do. And don't expect us to do it for you, though we will gladly help if you try and get stuck. Just post the code you have tried in the question.

Comment: So apparently someone already did your job for you in another question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221414/vlookup-to-compare-data-in-2-different-workbooks-with-vba
Is this some kind of entry-exam or what?

Comment: If your employer won't let you use a `VLOOKUP`, they will take a very dim view of using a macro (whether it uses a `Find` statement or not).  Employers would rather have solutions that do not require as much specialist knowledge to maintain, and `VLOOKUP` is built-in to Excel itself so they have already paid for it.

Answer (score 1):

To run this code you should be on your your first workbook and second work-book should be open in background, I find this as an easier method than to call workbook using it's address, you may change that if you like

```
Sub vl()
Dim lastrow As Long   

Sheets("Items").Select    
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC2,[Book2]Data!C4,1,FALSE),  ""OK"","""")"
```

End Sub

Here I assumed that *Name of your second book* is **Book2**.
Change it to whatever it is in the code.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please try running your code, then correct the errors, e.g. the references to column RC instead of B, and C instead of D (both due to using R1C1 notation in an A1 notation formula), and returning #N/A and #VALUE! errors (both due to assuming that `VLOOKUP` will return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` result).